# Trigger an event from another event in angular 5 and Material design 2

Tags: angular, material-design

I want to change a value of a radio button based on another radio button, but the event is never triggered and i have no console error. 
So let's say i click on the Honda car at position 5, so the brand Civic should be selected automaticly at position 5 in the form.

I'm using Angular 5 and Material design 2.

**Here's my template:**

```html
<mat-list> 
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let id of ids">
      <mat-radio-group>
        <mat-radio-button name="car" value="honda" id="honda{{id}}" (change)="onChangeCar(id,honda)">Honda</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="car" value="toyota" id="toyota{{id}}" (change)="onChangeCar(id,toyota)">Toyota</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
      <mat-radio-group>
        <mat-radio-button name="brand" value="civic" id="civic{{id}}" (change)="onChangeBrand(id)">Civic</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="brand" value="camry" id="camry{{id}}" (change)="onChangeBrand(id)">Camry</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
   </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

In the controller i tried this, but the brand is never triggered :

```js
@ViewChildren(MatRadioButton) rbuttons;
rbuttonsList: any[];

// This works
this.rbuttons.filter(x => x.id == 'brand13')[0].checked = true;
this.rbuttons.filter(x => x.id == 'brand131')[0].checked = true;

This give me en error : Cannot read property 'rbuttons' of undefined
// Get the ids that start with brand 13
this.rbuttonsList = this.rbuttons.filter(x => x.id.lastIndexOf('brand13', 0) === 0);
this.rbuttonsList.forEach(function (rbuttonIndex) {
    this.rbuttons.filter(x => x.id == rbuttonIndex.id)[0].checked = true;
  });
```

Comment: Where do you define `honda` and `toyota` as variables in your code? Did you open your console to check for errors?

Comment: Honda and Toyota are not defined as variable in the controller. Only in the view. Like i said, i have no console error

Comment: Did you intend to pass the string "honda" or "toyota" to the `onChangeCar` function? If so, you should enclose them in quotes, e.g., `onChangeCar(id, 'honda')`.

Comment: Selecting the element with `document` is not the way to go in Angular. See [How can I select an element in a component template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the change event that fires for the mat radio group. See documentation here:

https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api

Comment: @eric99, @ViewChild('myname') input;  is good to catch a unique id, but what about if i have dynamiq id's in my form ? like myname1, myname2, myname3, etc...

Comment: From Günter Zöchbauer's answer, I would try `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#civic' + id)`. You may have to fiddle with the selector.

Comment: There is also `@ViewChildren` which can select all your `mat-radio-button` and provide a QueryList which you can iterate through in your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to reference the element with dynamic ids in the template.

**ElementRef**

You can select using Angular's ElementRef instead of `document`. This gets you the native element, but there is no checked property on the native version of mat-radio-button, so this does not work for your purpose.

```js
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

onChangeCar (id, car) {
  if (car == 'honda') {
    let el = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#civic' + id)
    el.checked = true; // there is no 'checked' property to set 
  }
}
```

**ViewChildren**

Since id's are dynamic, instead of `ViewChild` which needs an explicit id, you can use `ViewChildren` and [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) methods. This works better since it uses the Angular element wrapper, and checked is available to be set (see rbutton on the console, there is a checked property).

```js
@ViewChildren(MatRadioButton) rbuttons;

onChangeCar (id, car) {
  if (car == 'honda') {
    let rbutton = this.rbuttons.filter(x => x.id == 'civic' + id);
    rbutton[0].checked = true;
  }
}
```

**By component property and template**

You can set via checked attribute on the template, referencing a component's property.

```js
brand = ''

onChangeCar (id, car) {
  this.brand = car; 
}
```

```html
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button name="brand" value="civic" id="civic{{id}}" 
    [checked]="brand === 'honda'"
    (change)="onChangeBrand(id)">Civic</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button name="brand" value="camry" id="camry{{id}}" 
    [checked]="brand === 'toyota'"
    (change)="onChangeBrand(id)">Camry</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7nv2a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (note both ViewChildren and property methods are active, so comment out one).

Comment: When i try to check multiple radiobutton inside a loop, i have an error : Cannot read property 'rbuttons' of undefined, But when i do it outside the loop it work. I edited my post to show you what i did so far and where the problem is

Comment: Ok, i replaced the foreach by a simple for and it works :)

Comment: Re your edit to the question code, I presume you are using `@ViewChildren(MatRadioButton) rbuttons;`

Comment: Something like `this.rbuttons.filter(x => x.id.lastIndexOf('brand13', 0) === 0).forEach(x => x[0].checked = true);`